# Measurable Set Proof for μ(A∪B∪C)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $I_0 = [a, b]$ and $a < b$. Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three measurable sets in $I$. Prove that:

$$\mu(A \cup B \cup C) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) + \mu(C) - \mu(A \cap B) - \mu(A \cap C) - \mu(B \cap C) + \mu(A \cap B \cap C).$$

Our book states that for two disjoint sets in $I$, $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, so I can see where the $μ(A) + μ(B) + μ(C)$ comes from, but I am having difficulty showing the other part. I have found a lot of statistics explanations online, but I need to show the proof in relation to measurable sets and math analysis. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $A, B, C$ are not disjoint, so the formula $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) \cup \mu(B)$ (which doesn't hold) is NOT where $\mu(A) + \mu(B) + \mu(C)$ come from.

Here's a hint.
Basically, you want to use the fact that $\mu(X \cup Y) = \mu(X) + \mu(Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint.
A few facts to start out with are
\begin{align*}
\mu(A \setminus B) + \mu(A \cap B) &= \mu(A) \\
\mu(B \setminus C) + \mu(B \cap C) &= \mu(B) \\
\mu(C \setminus A) + \mu(C \cap A) &= \mu(C) \\
\end{align*}
This should help you simplify the right-hand-side considerably.
Now notice that, since *all three* sets are disjoint,
we can add
$$
\mu(A \setminus B)
+ \mu(B \setminus C)
+ \mu(C \setminus A)
= \mu((A \cup B \cup C) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C))
$$
Finally, you should arrive at an equation with addition of two disjoint sets, which can be simplified in the same way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this and after applying the second equation you provided, I have arrived at this: μ((AUBUC)∖(A∩B∩C)) + μ(A∩B∩C).  I believe that this would reduce to μ(A∪B∪C).  Is this correct?

Comment: @lemonhead Yes.  This is because $U \setminus V$ and $U \cap V$ are always disjoint, and their union is $U$.  In this case $U = A \cup B \cup C$ and $V = A \cap B \cap C$.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that you have the structure given by the dyadic cubes.  In the one dimensional case, this is just the collection of closed intervals of the form $[\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i+1}{2^n}]$.  Let's start by proving this fact for dyadic cubes.  This might not be the simplest proof but it will work.

For just two dyadic cubes $I_1$ and $I_2$, either $I_1 \subset I_2$, $I_2 \subset I_1$, or they are disjoint.  If they are disjoint, $\mu(I_1 \cap I_2) = 0$, so $\mu(I_1 \cup I_2) = \mu(I_1)  + \mu(I_2)  - \mu(I_1 \cap I_2)$.  Otherwise, by symmetry we only consider $I_1 \subset I_2$.  Then $I_2 \cap I_1 = I_1$.  So $\mu(I_2 \cup I_1) = \mu(I_2) = \mu(I_2) + \mu(I_1) - \mu(I_1 \cap I_2)$.

Now for three dyadic cubes $I_1, I_2, I_3$, suppose first that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are disjoint.  Then either $I_3$ is disjoint from both, contains one (or both) of these cubes, or is contained in one of these cubes.  In all of these cases your result is trivial: $\mu(I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3) = 0$.

So suppose $I_1 \subset I_2$.  If $I_2$ and $I_3$ are disjoint the result is again trivial, so assume $I_2 \subset I_3$.  Then $\mu(I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3) = \mu(I_3)$.  Since $I_1 \cap I_3 = I_1$, and $I_2 \cap I_3 = I_2$, $\mu(I_1) + \mu(I_2) = \mu(I_1 \cap I_3) + \mu(I_2 \cap I_3)$, and since $I_1 \cap I_2 = I_1 = I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3$, $\mu(I_1 \cap I_2) = \mu(I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3)$, and your equality checks out.  Finally take $I_3 \subset I_2$.  If $I_3 \subset I_1$ the argument we just did can be reindexed, and your equality follows.  Otherwise, $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 = \emptyset$, and again your result follows.

This proves your equality in the case of countable unions of disjoint dyadic cubes by the additivity of Lebesgue measure.  If we had three countable unions of dyadic cubes, we could rewrite each of them as countable unions of disjoint cubes, and then our equality would apply.  Hence this identity holds for open sets.

You should be able to use dyadic cubes and outer regularity ($E$ is measurable only if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is open $U$ with $\mu(U\setminus E) \le \epsilon$) to finish this out.